# csv import fails without throwing an error

Tags: mysql, import, csv

Ι am trying to import a csv file into an existing `mysql 5.7` table.

Here is the command (the db is in docker with bind mount for persistence)

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -prootpass --local_infile=1 jira_statistics -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/centos/bugs.csv' INTO TABLE bugs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
```

However:

```
mysql> select * from bugs;
Empty set (0.05 sec)
```

The file cannot be loaded because there is a foreign key constraint.  I need to be able to catch errors like this (and any others that might occur) as an exit code since I will be scripting a large number of imports like this.

There is no error returned to the command line, and the `docker` logs of the MySQL container show no errors.

What is more, the exit code of the `mysql` command is `0`!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the `LOAD` in a Stored Procedure.  In there, capture the error and expose it to your script.

However, if `LOAD DATA` is not allowed in a Stored Proc, then you really need to write application code, *not* depend on on-line shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get an `%ERRORLEVEL%` returned by mysql, however you can get warnings printed to the console when `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` fails to insert values into columns for whatever reason, by adding the `--batch` option to the command-line.

I'm using Windows with MySQL 8.0.22; this is the test command I'm using in a .cmd file:

```
@"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysql.exe" --show-warnings --batch -h 127.0.0.1 -uxxx -pxxx --local_infile=1 test -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/temp/test.csv' INTO TABLE bugs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"
@ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The `/temp/test.csv` I'm using contains:

```
1
two,test
3
4
```

The `bugs` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bugs` (
  `i` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Output from running the batch file:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: 'two' for column 'i' at row 2
Warning (Code 1262): Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns
0
```

As you can see, there is a warning presented telling us that `'two'` could not be inserted into the column for `i`.  The row was also truncated since there is no column for the value 'test'.

The `0` on the last line is the `%errorlevel%` value.

I tried adding the `LOAD DATA` command to a stored proc so that I could create an exit handle for SQL Exceptions, however MySQL blocks the use of `LOAD DATA` inside a stored procedure.  This is the error:

```
Error Code: 1314. LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures
```